# capture specific range of comma separated strings in a regex

Tags: regex

I want to make a regex that captures only the first 3 comma separated strings in

brand1,brand2,brand3,brand4,brand5,brand6,brand7,brand8,brand9

So the desired result is keep only
brand1,brand2,brand3

What I have tried and doesn't work is:

```
^(.*\,.*\,.*)\,.*?$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, and you only need to use negative character classes here to match the content in between commas:

```
^[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*
```

If you wanted to salvage your current approach, you could make the `.*` *lazy*:

```
^(.*?,.*?,.*?),.*$
```